# Is "calling" a gerund in "calling bell"?

Tags: adjectives, gerunds, ing, gerund-phrases

In the phrase "calling bell", the word "calling" acts as what? Is it a gerund? Or is it an adjective?
If so then what kind of adjective? Similar phrases might be "revolving door", or "racing pigeon", etc. I understand that the *ing word describes the following noun, but I'm not exactly sure about its grammatical properties.

Comment: What if it's a bell belonging to Fred Calling?

Comment: @John Can you tell us what you mean by "calling bell". An example.would help. Btw, I can honestly say that I've never heard it used.

Comment: @BillJ It's a door bell, or a bell that's used to seek attention of someone else.

Comment: @John In that case, "calling-bell" is a compound noun. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> *calling-bell*

It all boils down to whether "calling bell" means a static door bell or a bell that is actively calling in order to seek attention.

In the static door bell reading it's a compound noun, hyphenated, consisting of a gerund-participle verb + noun, with a purposive meaning: "bell for calling". It's pronounced with the main stress on the first element.

Similar examples include *frying-pan* ("pan for frying"), *chewing-gum* ("gum for chewing"), *walking-stick* ("stick for walking") and the like.

In the actively calling (i.e. ringing) reading it's a syntactic construction consisting of the noun "bell" as head modified by the gerund-participial verb "calling". The main stress here is on the second element.

Note that in both cases, "calling" is a verb.

Answer (score 1):

-ing words can be gerunds or present participles, and have different meanings depending on which they are. When you have a phrase of the form "verbing noun", if "verbing" is a gerund, then this means "noun having to do with verbing". If "verbing" is a present participle, then it means "noun that is currently engaged in verbing". A gerund is talking about the nature of the noun, while a participle is talking about the noun's current activity. If you are communicating that a door is currently revolving, then "revolving" in "revolving door" is a participle. If you are saying that it is a door that is *designed* to revolve, regardless of whether it is currently revolving, then it is a gerund.

Comment: You have a lot of info here that requires "unpacking".

Comment: I basically agree with you, after all a 'lunging rein' hanging in a tack room is still a lunging rein even though it's not attached to a horse.

Comment: I think you're making this much more complicated than it actually is. _-Ing_ participles and gerunds and verbs, but there are also _-ing_ nouns and _-ing_ adjectives. Consider these examples: _They were  criticised for killing the seals_ (verb) ~ _They witnessed the killing of the seals_ (noun). _We are entertaining the neighbours tonight_ (verb) ~ _The show was very entertaining_ (adjective).

Comment: However, assuming that the OP's "calling-bell" means a static door bell or similar, then it's a compound noun, hyphenated, consisting of ing verb + noun, meaning "bell for calling". (see my answer).

Comment: @BillJ, How does *killing* become a verb in your sentence *They were criticized for killing the seals*?  'For' is a preposition and 'killing' is its object, isn't it? Can a verb function like this? So, isn't it a gerund?

Comment: @mahmudkpukayoor No: clauses can't function as objects of preps, but they can function as complements. Note that gerunds are verbs, not nouns. Verbs and nouns differ in the kinds of complementation they take. Most notably, verbs can take NP objects (like "seals") whereas the corresponding nouns take an _of_ PP, as in my other example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by “a calling bell” here. To my mind, you have two mutually exclusive choices:

1. It’s *a bell **for** calling* in the same way that a calling card is a card for making calls with, for calling people with. Some people have doors with calling bells that ring out to alert them visitors. They’re bells **for** the calling of someone’s attention.
2. It’s *a bell that **is** calling*  in the same way that the four calling birds so famously involved with the twelve drummers drumming and eleven pipers piping and nine ladies dancing are actually birds that **are** calling, drummers that are drumming, pipers that are piping, and ladies that are dancing.

If case one applies, it’s a noun.

If case two applies, it’s a verb.

And sometimes it’s ambiguous in isolation like this. After all, a *singing instructor* might be an instructor who gives choral lessons, but it might also be an instructor who happens to be singing out loud right at this very moment.

But no matter which case or cases apply here, this noun or verb is acting as a **modifier** of the noun *bell*. It isn’t a verb whose direct object is *bell*.

Comment: It's difficult to see how "calling" could be a noun in 1.

Comment: The other option is a bell that is rung when a person discovers their calling.   “I just realized I’m supposed to be a welder!  *<ring>*”